Derive time taken from start time and end time
I have a dataframe that adopts the following structure:
start_time <- c("09:00:00.000", "09:23:00.000", "09:23:00.000", "15:37:00.000")
end_time <- c("09:50:00.000", "09:50:00.000","09:50:00.000","16:10:00.000")
CO.TimeTaken <- data.frame(start_time, end_time)

> CO.TimeTaken

   start_time     end_time
1 09:00:00.000 09:50:00.000
2 09:23:00.000 09:50:00.000
3 09:23:00.000 09:50:00.000
4 15:37:00.000 16:10:00.000

I'd like to mutate and create a new column called TimeTaken, which is a numeric column that contains values in minutes based on end_time minus start_time
I have tried using lubridate package to extract minutes but the output is not the desired one which I want. These are the steps I used.
library(lubridate)
CO.TimeTaken$start_time <- hms(as.character(CO.TimeTaken$start_time))
CO.TimeTaken$end_time <- hms(as.character(CO.TimeTaken$end_time))
CO.TimeTaken$TimeTaken <- CO.TimeTaken$end_time - CO.TimeTaken$start_time

Output of the above code
> CO.TimeTaken
  start_time   end_time  TimeTaken
1   9H 0M 0S  9H 50M 0S     50M 0S
2  9H 23M 0S  9H 50M 0S     27M 0S
3  9H 23M 0S  9H 50M 0S     27M 0S
4 15H 37M 0S 16H 10M 0S 1H -27M 0S

What should I do to achieve the above outcome?

One option is doing the following, but I am not sure if that is what are you looking for:
> library(dplyr)
> CO.TimeTaken |> 
+   mutate(
+     TimeTaken = as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(end_time, format = "%H:%M:%OS"), 
+                                     as.POSIXct(start_time, format = "%H:%M:%OS"), 
+                                     units = "mins"))
+   )
    start_time     end_time TimeTaken
1 09:00:00.000 09:50:00.000        50
2 09:23:00.000 09:50:00.000        27
3 09:23:00.000 09:50:00.000        27
4 15:37:00.000 16:10:00.000        33


If your times were POSIX formatted, you could briefly do.call 'difftime'.
> transform(d, mins=as.integer(do.call('difftime', c(unname(rev(d)), units='mins'))))
           start_time            end_time mins
1 2024-04-09 09:00:00 2024-04-09 09:50:00   50
2 2024-04-09 09:23:00 2024-04-09 09:50:00   27
3 2024-04-09 09:23:00 2024-04-09 09:50:00   27
4 2024-04-09 15:37:00 2024-04-09 16:10:00   33

However, you may still do
> mk_tm <- \(x) as.POSIXct(x, f='%T')
> transform(d, mins=as.integer(do.call('difftime', c(unname(lapply(rev(d), mk_tm)), units='mins'))))
    start_time     end_time mins
1 09:00:00.000 09:50:00.000   50
2 09:23:00.000 09:50:00.000   27
3 09:23:00.000 09:50:00.000   27
4 15:37:00.000 16:10:00.000   33


Data:
> dput(d)
structure(list(start_time = c("09:00:00.000", "09:23:00.000", 
"09:23:00.000", "15:37:00.000"), end_time = c("09:50:00.000", 
"09:50:00.000", "09:50:00.000", "16:10:00.000")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

